# How to uninstall msi with full UI?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, registry

I have created a msi installer with wix ToolSet v3.11
After I install that msi installer, when I try to uninstall, it uninstalls with only basic UI.
I want to show the dialog when uninstall.
I think when uninstall product in Apps & Features in windows, msiexec /x {GUID} /qb is running.
I want to run msiexec /x {GUID} /qf when uninstall.
How to do this?
Anyone knows help me.

I tried to change the uninstall string in registry but not working.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Installer does not show the internal UI of an MSI package during uninstall. The behavior you are seeing is as it is designed.